# gcc compiling error: no input files/fork

Tags: c, makefile

When I go to create an object file for my runsim.c file for my "makefile" 
I obtain this error message:

> gcc: fatal error: no input files

I am unsure how to correct this. I provided my code, but I do not think the problem would be there? Would I need an .h file? Also Is the implementation of my fork() process correct? I am to use the 'testsim.c' file along with the code below to take a command line argument and run it based on the number of processes to run

> i.e. runsim 2 < test.data

'runsim' being the executable from the makefile

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("testsim.c", "w+");

    int childpid;
    int pr_count;
    pr_count = 0;

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    int i;
    int pr_limit;

    read  = getline(&line, &len, file);
    int MAX_BUF;
    MAX_BUF  = read;
    char buf[MAX_BUF];


    pr_limit = atoi(argv[1]);
    for (i = 0; i < pr_limit; i++)
    {
            childpid = fork();

            if (childpid == 0) // Child Process Code
            {
                    if (argc != 2)
                    {
                            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s processes\n", argv[0]);
                            return 1;
                    }

                    while(!feof(file))
                    {
                            if (pr_count == pr_limit)
                            {
                                    waitpid(-1, &pr_count, WNOHANG);
                                    pr_count--;
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                    fgets(buf, MAX_BUF, file);
                            }
                    }

                    fclose(file);
                    waitpid(-1, &pr_count, WNOHANG);
                    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                    fprintf(stderr, "i: %d process ID: %ld parent ID: %ld child ID: %ld\n", i, (long)getpid(), (long)getppid(),(long)childpid);

            pr_count--;
            }

            if(childpid < 0)
            {
                    perror("Error: waitpid() failed\n");//Fork Failed
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Makefile included:

```
CC = gcc

CFLAGS = -Wall -ansi

LIBS =

OBJ = runsim.o testsim.o

stats: $(OBJ)

        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o runsim $(OBJ) $(LIBS)


runsim.o: runsim.c

        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) runsim.c


testsim.o: testsim.c

        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) testsim.c


.PHONY: clean

clean:

        -rm *.o $(OBJ) runsim
```

An error occures when i try to run 'make' as seen below:

```
runsim.c: In function âmainâ:
runsim.c:22:2: warning: implicit declaration of function âgetlineâ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  read  = getline(&line, &len, file);
 ^
runsim.c:33:22: error: expected expression before â/â token
   if (childpid == 0) // Child Process Code
                  ^
runsim.c:25:7: warning: unused variable âbufâ [-Wunused-variable]
  char buf[MAX_BUF];
       ^
runsim.c:13:6: warning: variable âpr_countâ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  int pr_count; 
      ^
make: *** [runsim.o] Error 1
```

Comment: It's not related to the code. What is your makefile?

Comment: check you makefile for arguments to gcc, it should be something like `gcc runsim.c` or if you are using varibles, make sure it is initialized with proper values

Comment: Need to see that Makefile.

Comment: my make file generates errors to will proide the errors @HolyBlackCat

Comment: Ok it **is** related to the code, but that's only obvious after your edit. What I find confusing: Your output of `make` doesn't match what you wrote earlier -- how did you get a message about **no input files**?

Comment: @FelixPalmen I guess what i am asking is why won't the program compile with my make? I do not have *.o files for my 'make' because my runsim.c file will not allow me to create them per the provided errors.

Comment: You are trying to do too many things at once. Try something simpler. Can you build `runsim.o` using the command line? Can you build `HelloWorld` using Make?